# Одновременное открытие и сокрытие блоков на javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько элементов управления, пусть это будут ссылки, кликая на которые можно открыть блоки с определёнными id (изначально эти блоки `style="display:none"`). То есть, кликая на кнопку `id="k1"` открываем блок с `id="b1"`, и так далее. Если нажать на эту же кнопку повторно, то блок скроется. За данный механизм отвечает кусок javascripta

```
function viewdiv(id){ 
var el=document.getElementById(id); 
if(el.style.display=="block")
{ el.style.display="none"; } 
else 
{ el.style.display="block"; } 
}
```

ну а на каждую кнопку повешено onclick

```
<a id="kN" onclick="viewdiv('bN');"    >
```

где N - цифра, идентификатор блока и кнопки

Вопрос в том - как сделать, чтобы одновременно мог быть открыт только один блок? Например, при открытии блока с `id="bN"` скрывать все блоки с `id != "bN"`

Внимание! JQuery нельзя, по условиям задания... только чистый js

UPD по просьбе сообщества добавляю разметку - она очень проста:

```
<a id="k1" onclick="viewdiv(b1)" ></a>
<div id="b1" style="display:none;">Im div number 1</div>
<a id="k2" onclick="viewdiv(b2)" ></a>
<div id="b2" style="display:none;">Im div number 2</div>
```

Comment: Заранее известны id всех блоков? Можно дорабатывать html?

Comment: @Skywave да, id все заранее известны, а вот html дорабатывать нельзя, если вы имеете в виду добавление каких-то новых тегов

Comment: добавьте тогда разметку, раз ее менять нельзя

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавил, она простая

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если все id заранее известны, то я бы сделал отдельный метод

```
let ids = ['id1','id2','id3'];
function hideAll() {
  for(var i in ids) {
    let elem = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
    elem.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

и вызывал бы его перед каждым показом

```
function viewdiv(id){ 
  var el=document.getElementById(id); 
  if(el.style.display=="block")
  { el.style.display="none"; } 
  else 
  {
    hideAll();
    el.style.display="block";
  } 
}
```

Проще, чем сравнивать id и решать кто должен скрыться а кто не должен. Просто скрываем все и показываем тот, что нужен.

Comment: я тоже думаю, что просто скрывать все и показывать тот, что нужен - логично было бы, но приведённый вами код работать не желает

Comment: я не проверял его на работоспособность, но думаю идею вы поняли =)

Comment: да, в какую сторону ковырять я понял, спасибо

Comment: а вы знаете - таки заработал ваш код))) просто функцию hideAll нужно было вызывать не после else а после if)))

Comment: а для моих целей вполне пойдёт) там всего не более 5 идентификаторов будет

Comment: @Alexandros и вы будете перечислять вручную идентификаторы? это из разряда вредные советы =)) т.к. каждый раз когда будет меняться разметка надо будет править этот код =)

Comment: @Alexandros ok, дело хозяйское =))

Comment: Я вам больше скажу - задачу я здесь поставил упрощённо, а вообще это даже не html-страница и не div'ы))) Это SVG-файл, в котором надо организовать некую интерактивность, т.е. при клике на определённые svg-элементы открывать/скрывать другие svg-элементы))) @Skywave еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @Alexandros да я помню, я недавно для Вас писал извращение по клику на svg и back буффером

Answer (score 0):

Вариант номер 1: запоминать что было показано в прошлый раз и прятать его

```js
let opened;
function viewdiv(id) {
  opened && (opened.style.display = "none");
  (opened = id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<a id="k1" onclick="viewdiv(b1)" >link 1</a>
<div id="b1" style="display:none;">Im div number 1</div>
<a id="k2" onclick="viewdiv(b2)" >link 2</a>
<div id="b2" style="display:none;">Im div number 2</div>
```

---

Вариант номер 2: Если других div с идентификаторами на странице нет или есть другая возможность использовать групповой селектор, то можно скрывать их все, а потом показывать нужный

```js
function viewdiv(id) {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('div[id]')].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
  id.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<a id="k1" onclick="viewdiv(b1)" >link 1</a>
<div id="b1" style="display:none;">Im div number 1</div>
<a id="k2" onclick="viewdiv(b2)" >link 2</a>
<div id="b2" style="display:none;">Im div number 2</div>
```

Comment: другие div'ы на странице, естественно, есть - это же сайт)

Comment: поэтому я просил добавить разметку, важны детали, в какой блок это все вложено? может у него есть id или класс

Comment: @Alexandros поэтому я просил добавить разметку, важны детали, в какой блок это все вложено? может у него есть id или класс, может есть шаблон по которому id составлены...